Should I include location fixed effects if I'm interested in part of the variation across locations when people move?
I have a panel consisting of individuals who moved at some point within the panel's time frame, where the panel ID (id) represents individuals, and the time ID (date) represents days of the year. The average number of observations per year for each id is 2 (this doesn't mean that the person moves twice; just that their data is updated twice). I want to understand the impact on the individual binary variable y (for example, being married) of moving to a neighborhood with attribute X versus attribute Z, using the difference-in-differences method. It's important to note that this attribute can take other values (such as W and K) and varies yearly. In other words, the treatment is at the neighborhood-year level. Since people move at different times, I understand that the correct approach is a generalized DID with two-way fixed effects.
The model looks like:
$y_{it} = treat_{it} + \alpha_{i} + \beta_{t}$
Where $treat$ is moving to neighborhood with attribute X, $\alpha_{it}$ are individual fixed effects, and $\beta_{t}$ are time fixed effects. I will run the regression only for neighborhoods with attributes X and Z and times -1 and 0, clustering at the neighborhood and year level.
My question is: since I'm interest in capturing the effect of the variation in attributes between neighborhoods, should I include neighborhood fixed effects?
Also, if this is needed, will them be redundant with the individuals fixed effects of the TWFE?
